# Using Camel File Language

Tags: file, apache-camel

We are trying to use the move, preMove and Error options of the file component. 
Here is our directory structure like

//root/child/ic/dir1/child1
//root/child/ic/dir1/child2

When a file is read to be processed from child1, we would like it to be moved to inprogress within child1 and then to processed at //root/child/ic/dir1//processed

We have tried many combinations of file language syntax and nothing seems to work. Here are few examples

for 
move/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}
The date component never resolves the pattern to a real date and file:name also does not resolve
How do I give ?move=../processed so that the file is moved one directory up to //root/child/ic/
llly

I would also like to move the transformed file to a folder relative to the //root/child/ic/. we have the root folder set at ${user.home}/root/child/ic. How can we give relative path without having to hard code it since we have many child folder and we would like the transfored file to be kept relative to the child folder.

Comment: Nothing works? What happens, and what Camel version do you use? And are you using linux or windows. Check the docs, see the unit tests etc.

Comment: We resolved this. The problem is that camel does not allow dynamic path binding in yaml files. By dynamic I mean ..using relative directories by moving up by one as shown in example ../

Answer (score 1):

```
 When we did the following in our consts file it worked.public static final String FILE_COMPONENT_CONFIG = "file:{xxx.agent.rootDir}}?" +
      "preMove={{xxx.agent.preMove}}&" +
      "move=${file:parent}/../{{xxx.agent.move}}/${file:onlyname.noext.single}_${date:now:yyyyMMdd-hhmmss}.${file:name.ext}&" +
      "moveFailed=${file:parent}/../{{xxxx.agent.moveFailed}}/${file:onlyname.noext.single}_${date:now:yyyyMMdd-hhmmss}.${file:name.ext}&" +
      "idempotent={{xxx.agent.idempotent}}&" +
      "idempotentRepository=#trackRepository&" +
      "delay=30000&" +
      "include={{xxxx.agent.include}}&" +
      "recursive=true&" +
      "minDepth=2&" +
      "antExclude={{xxxx.agent.exclude}}";
```